# Why does the C++ std::unordered_map returning an iterator from emplace / find?

Tags: c++

I understand why an unordered_map has an iterator (begin() and end()) but I don't see what value returning an iterator from find / emplace is.

I can't imagine a use case where you would want to start your iterator at a given key as opposed to begin / end (because a good hash function should make the position of a key in the table arbitrary).

The alternative; to just return the value, reference to the value, or pair of key and value covers all use cases I can imagine an avoids the unnecessary work of creation an iterator and likely causing an additional memory deference when using it to access the underlying pair / value.

Comment: What if `find` does not find the value? What do you return then?

Comment: Returning a copy of the value or a pair of key and value is much more "unnecessary work" than returning an iterator. Iterators are cheap.

Comment: depending on the type that is probably true. A pointer to the underlying pair (or just underlying value) however would be less expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you want to remove the item? What if you want to extract or merge it? What if you want to use it as a hint to emplace?